# How do I rebuild a VMhost datastore following a corrupted installation

Tags: vmware-esxi, corruption, datastore

My server was shutdown at the weekend for a planned power outage to our building.  When I tried to the bring the server back up, along with some errors about logical drives that did not exist (now sorted) I have found myself with a corrupted SD card which contained the ESXi 4 installation.

I have replaced the SD card and reinstalled ESXi 4 to it.  I am currently running in 30 day trial mode as I don't have access to our license information at present.

I need to be able to restore the datastore that was originally on the logical drive.

I have viewed the storage adapters and these appears to be similar to another server that I have, however, there aren't any WWN details listed.

I then clicked on Storage | Add Storage | Disk option

I have nothing available to me here.

How do I get my data back??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of server and storage hardware do you have? Make and model, please. Also, how was your VM storage connected to the host? In addition, was this a *single* host server, or part of a cluster? Where is your Virtual Center?